# how to compare the hierarchical order of two subviews?

Tags: iphone, hierarchy, subview

I want to find a way how I can compare the actual hierarchical order of two subviews.

As i didn't find a method who turns out to give me this kind of result, I want to ask you. Im sure there must be a way to do this.

Is it possible, that the [view subviews] array is ordered with the same hierarchy?

Thanks,
Makrus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I have not find any reference about that in docs I'm pretty sure that the order of elements in `subviews` array corresponds to their z-order. You can try to change order of subviews in IB and log subviews to console - you will see that output supports that.

One more hint that it is really so are `insertSubview:atIndex:` and `exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:` methods which change subview's z-order and those changes are reflected in subviews array order...